# XMLDocument onreadystatechange does not fire in chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a piece of JavaScript code that is working fine in IE but in chrome onreadystatechange event does not fire.

```
var oXml = document.createElement("XML");
document.body.appendChild(oXml);
oS = new Object();
oS.sXmlHttp = null;
oS.aXmlHttp = null;
oS.fPending = true;
oS.nextCall = null;
oS.lastCall = null;
oS.url = url;
oS._oXml = oXml;
oS.ns = new Array();
oS.nsalias = new Array();
if (options != null) {
    oS.fSeq = options.reuseConnection;
    oS.SOAPHeader = options.SOAPHeader;
}
if (oS.fSeq == null)
    oS.fSeq = false;
_sdl[url] = oS;
oXml.service = userName;
oXml.onreadystatechange = getWsdl //event funtion not fires in chrome;
oXml.src = url;
```

In above code onreadystatechange not fires in chrome.
Any help please?

Comment: Can anybody solve my problem? Is there any JavaScript guru??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that chrome not fires the event. It is just that the event does not exist.

```
var oXml = document.createElement("XML");
console.log( typeof oXml.onreadystatechange ); // this prints "undefined"
```

Comment: I aslo tried by using this:
var parser = new DOMParser();
  var oXml = parser.parseFromString ("<XML/>", "text/xml");
  //var oXml = document.createElement("XML");

Comment: I want to let onreadystatechange event fire when xml state get change.

Comment: Yeah i can see that but, why? You create an xml element inside HTML, this is not valid... 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla
If you wnat to do something using xml you have to parse it into something else.

Comment: You are right but this is the requirement actually there is a website working fine in IE9, and i need to convert it into chrome.i need to follow each line of code to prevent the ripples That is why i am doing this all.